# Is it possible to initialize a UserControl as a StaticResource to be used inside a ContentControl

Tags: c#, xaml, user-controls, blend, win-universal-app

I'm currently dipping my toes into writing Universal Apps for the windows platform, for one of my attempts I'd like to try and make a one of these snazzy new single page apps.

However, I'd like to re-use my code where possible so that I follow DRY principles and don't repeat any code that I don't need to.

As such, I've made a number of User controls *(which all work fine on their own)* and I'm attempting to embed them inside an Xaml **ContentControl** ultimately allowing me to swap different ContentControl objects in and out of view at run time.

So far, in my experiments, I have the following code:

***XAML:***

```
<ContentControl x:Name="CentralContextHost" Style="{StaticResource ContentControlStyle}">
  <!-- The following tag is which ever user control I wish to host -->
  <Universal:CentralHubControl/>
</ContentControl>
```

***And the code behind I use to manipulate the above XAML:***

```
public object CurrentControl; // field

if (CurrentControl == null)
  CurrentControl = new Profile(); // another usercontrol

var tempswap = CentralContextHost.Content;
CentralContextHost.Content = CurrentControl;
CurrentControl = tempswap;
```

I would however like to try and make my code much cleaner by using something similar to the binding syntax I've seen used elsewhere by possibly creating my controls as static resources in a dictionary of some kind xaml object, then just dropping a similar deceleration to a bind in the correct position in my xaml to have them display as needed.

The problem I have is that I'm not really sure how to approach solving this problem, or if there is even a way that it can be solved.  My idea is to be able to do something similar to the following fictitious bit of code.

```
<Universal:CentralHubControl x:Key="CentralHub" />
<Universal:Profile x:Key="PersonProfile" />

<ContentControl
  x:Name="CentralContextHost"
  Grid.RowSpan="2"
  Content="{StaticResource CentralHub}"
  Style="{StaticResource ContentControlStyle}">
```

This seems to work in blend but crashes badly when used at run time.

can anyone here see why that might be or what I might be doing wrong?

If you need any more info please ask in the comments and let me know, I'd love to find an answer to both questions here.

Comment: I tried to solve this problem with DataTemplateSelectors but they don't seem to maintain VisualStates that I'm using to page state. the only way that works is using code-behind and initializing the items from there - it all seems a bit too bespoke and I'd like a more MVVM friendly approach.

Answer (score 1):

I've not played with an app that has everything in one page myself yet. If I did, perhaps I might suggest using a panel as your content host instead of a **contentcontrol**.

For example, if you were to have a Grid as the root of your layout, which by default it usually is. You can then add your user controls directly to the panel in the code behind by using the following line of code:

```
rootLayout.Children.Add(AnyUIElement).
```

Doing things this way may make it possible to create a new instance of the wanted user control and potentially maintain state for it.

For an *MVVM* style solution, I'll have to play around with the concept.

Is there a specific reason you need to use a **contentcontrol** that I may not have considered?

Comment: I'd like it to be visible in Blend for the designer to edit it as well as available to me at runtime. It looks like I can have one or the other. I'm trying to create a MVVM friendly single page app with iOS style transitions of content pages rather than the page-shifty windows style. was just wondering if I can skip the code-behind.

Comment: I'll have a play around with some ideas over the weekend and let you know if I come up with anything that might be of use to you.

Comment: Thanks, I'm a bit fed-up of page swapping in Windows apps and thought I'll get them to look more like iOS style apps to up the quality of the page-transitions

Comment: With a bit of play, I'm my multi-page apps I've managed some nice transitions between pages, rather than the flicker type jump it does. Have you seen the 'Great British Chefs' app. Is it something like that you are after.

Comment: I like it, but it still has a jarry white background during the transition. what I want to see is the selected content carried around to the next detail screen, some useful expansions of existing controls while the rest disappears.

Comment: Yeah I get what you mean. I have some ideas on a control that may do what you need. There are also controls like the hub. It may be possible to make some changes to that to achieve the same effect.

I'll shoot you a message if, as said, I can come up with something that could help you.